# STL List Insert asks for 3 arguments

Tags: c++, stl, arguments, singly-linked-list

Working with an STL list today. First time using one, and I'm not terribly familiar with the member functions, and I'm not sure I fully understand iterators. Non-the-less, I have done the research, and cannot seem to understand why the insert function from the STL list is demanding I pass it 3 arguments

```
note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
Houses.insert(it,temp);
```

here is a segement of my code. Just for reference, this bit appears multiple times throughout, and the error crops up at every instance.

```
temp = new WolfDen;
it = Houses.begin();
Houses.insert(it,temp);
temp -> setDimensions();
```

Houses is my STL list of "homes". WolfDen is a derived class of homes. temp is homes pointer, and it is my list iterator.

Comment: `Working with an STL list today. First time using one`: What book are you referring?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: At least show the definition of `Houses`, I have a sneaking suspicion you've defined it as `std::list<home>` rather than `std::list<home*>`.

Comment: That is exactly what I've done. Can you explain the difference to me? I know one is a list of pointers and the other is a list of objects, but how does that change the interaction?

Comment: I'm using Data Structures and Other Objects Using C++ 4th edition

Comment: `std::list<home>` stores actual `home` objects, `std::list<home*>` stores *pointers* to homes, you generally use the latter when you need to acess the objects polymorphically which I assume is what you're doing. A pointer is not an object, so when you try to insert a pointer to a `home` your compiler doesn't know what to do with it because it expects a `home` value. Modern C++ would use `std::list<std::unique_ptr<home>>` instead of raw pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assumptions

Based on the comments `Houses` is probably defined as

```
std::list<Home> Houses;
```

and `WolfDen` inherits from Home;

```
class WolfDen : public Home
```

### Store Polymorphic Objects

Since you probably intend to use the whole `WolfDen` object, you need to store the pointer:

```
std::list<Home *> Houses;
```

or in modern C++ (since C++11):

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<Home>> Houses;
```

If you use the bare pointer variant `std::list<Home *>`, be sure to delete the objects pointed to, once you are done with them. E.g. right before leaving the scope in which `Houses` is defined do

```
for (std::list<Home *>::const_iterator homeIt  = Houses.begin(),
                                       homeEnd = Houses.end();
     homeIt != homeEnd; ++homeIt)
{
    delete *homeIt;
}
```

### Store By-Value

If you stay with your definition as `std::list<Home>`, the following insert statement will compile:

```
Houses.insert(it,*temp);
```

But this would insert another `Home` object into `Houses` which is a copy only of the `Home` part of the `WolfDen` object `*temp` stored at the location pointed to by `temp`. (The new object will be `Houses.front()`)

The subsequent modification

```
temp->setDimensions();
```

will only modify the original object `*temp` and not `Houses.front()`. Also, the object `*temp` will probably leak, unless you add

```
delete temp;
```

at the end of your code.

However, it is much better, not to use pointers at all:

```
Home temp;
temp.setDimensions();
it = Houses.begin();
Houses.insert(it,temp);
```

(Note, that class `WolfDen` is not used, since only the `Home` part will be used anyway.)

### Understanding the error message

```
note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
```

To understand this, have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert: The version you intend to call is  version (1) of `std::list::insert`

```
iterator insert( iterator pos, const T & value ); (1)
```

where T is Home. I.e.

```
iterator insert( iterator pos, const Home & value );
```

For the parameter `pos` you provide an argument of type `std::list<Home>::iterator`, which is fine. But for the parameter `value` you provide an argument of type `Home *` (or possibly `WolfDen *` which converts to `Home *`), which is a pointer. Pointers do not convert to values (or references to values in this case) implicitly. The match with the version (1) therefore fails.

However, pointers convert to integer types implicitly. Since there are other versions of `std::list::insert`, the compiler tries these, as well. The first two provided arguments match to version (3) in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert:

```
void insert( iterator pos, size_type count, const T & value ); (3)
```

The pointer of type `Home *` converts to `size_type`. But then the third argument `value` is missing... Some compilers are more elaborate and list the possible candidates and also more information about the failed matches.

If `value` would not be needed, you code might have compiled. Since pointers are usually converted to rather large values, your application would have added a rather large number of entries to `Houses`.  (You can try this by changing your code to `Houses.insert(it,temp, WolfDen());`. But be prepared to run out of memory ;-)).